# why image size is reduce when I used background-image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a image using `background-image` and `img src` tag. I am confused when I am using same image using `background-image` **it become smaller**  .but when I used as `img` src tag it look good why ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-cartwright-pw2mq?file=/src/styles.css

```
<div class="curve-img-container">

jjjj
    </div>

        <img src="src/bg-curvy-desktop.svg" alt="">
```

my output is this

[image]

why there is a difference  ??in both case it look same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `background-image` CSS property sets **background images** on an element so the size of that element decides the dimension of the image

In your case, you have set the styles for `div` element:

- `width: 100%` - which will take 100% of the viewport
- `height: 200px` - which will set both the element and the image height to 200px

While `<img>` element embeds an image into the document which means the browser will render the image as it is (without changing its dimension).

In your case the dimension of the image is:

- `width: 1440px; height:449px;`

Answer (score 0):

The background image appears with respect to the `height` and `width` of the element you are setting it to. When you use image tag initialy it loads with actual `height` and `width` of the image ( which is different comparing to your div ) **so they appear different.**

So in your case if you want both of them to look a like you need same `height` and `width` for img and div.

So for example you can do these if you want both of them to look the same.

Note that `object-fit: cover;object-position: center;` is equivalent of `background-size: cover;background-position: center;` of css, Hope this answers your doubt

And as a side note always use img tag as it better for SEO.

```css
img{
    height: 50px;
    width : 50px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
.mydiv{
    height: 50px;
    width : 50px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" style="background-image : url(https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg)"></div>

<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the css value `background-repeat: no-repeat` for prevent the background image from duplicating itself in the div.

For controlling the background image size inside the div, read about the css property `background-size`: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score -1):

in your code sample you have set the height for the container of the image background to 200px, so the image will take this height also as it is relative to what ever its container size...

Please note also that you should consider the background size as it is going to be auto by default, this will prevent the background from stretching and will keep the height/width percentage to prevent image being distorted.

Comment: how both image look same

Comment: i applied `background-size` see ouput https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-cartwright-pw2mq?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: You missed the point of my explanation, you asked why the image as background image looks smaller?? This is because it takes the width and height of the container and applies to it

Comment: how both look same ?? `img` tag is correct one ..background is wrong ? how to correct them ?

Comment: In your case you set the height to 200 so maximum height for the background image is 200, while img tag will be considered as an element and will render the image in its full size

Comment: To let them both look the same you have to either set dimensions for the div tag to be same width and height of the original image or to unite dimensions for both of div and img